# Remove or disable onclick listener for table row using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, row

I'm dynamically adding rows to a table using vanilla js as follows:

```
// insert new row
var row = table.insertRow()
// add click listener to row
row.onclick = (function rowClickListener(){
     // delete row on click
    table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex)
})
```

But when another function is running I want to disable the onclick functionality (so users can't delete the table item during process) for the duration of that function. I've tried unsuccessfully:

```
row.disabled = true
// and
row.removeEventListener('click', rowClickListener)
```

Is what I'm attempting even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your current `function rowClickListener` is a *function expression*, not a *function declaration*, so no `rowClickListener` variable gets created in the outer scope. You need a reference to the function variable in order to `removeEventListener`.

Also, in order to `removeEventListener`, you need the function to have been added via `addEventListener`:

```
function rowClickListener(){
  table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex)
}
row.addEventListener('click', rowClickListener);
// later...
row.removeEventListener('click', rowClickListener);
```

If you wanted to go the `onclick` route, then you can remove the listener by assigning `null` to it:

```
row.onclick = () => table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
// later...
row.onclick = null;
```

Comment: This did it! Brilliant thank you. I'd upvote your answer if I had the reputation so someone please commend this fine person.